# PayPal gateway has rejected request (#10413)

Tags: paypal, magento2, payment-request-api

I have migrated our Magento store 1.9 to 2.3. I have only one tax policy 10% for US California customers.
But I tried to make the payment with California address it came back to cart page with error.

**PayPal gateway has rejected request. The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid**

When I checked the code, it shows tax twice, but I couldn't find the where its coming from.

**Is there any solution for that**

Answer (score 0):

Need to narrow down the issue first:

1. Check if having class preference and plugins and observer events that override or being triggered while processing Paypal gateway.
2. Also check if the issue still exists by removing tax policy 10% US California customers

Hope it helps, thanks